# typedef enum to Swift enum. How to use cases to mark Pause and Resume of detection of idleTimerDisabled?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Worked out a Swift enum declaration from an Obj-C typedef enum but now I don't know how to implement it in Swift. I was shown a function but I don't know what I'd use for the two cases to set idle/awake? How would I mark Pause and Resume of detection of idleTimerDisabled?

```
//  ViewController.m   

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>  // import AVFoundation
#import "PulseDetector.h"
#import "Filter.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, CURRENT_STATE) {
STATE_PAUSED,
STATE_SAMPLING
};

#define MIN_FRAMES_FOR_FILTER_TO_SETTLE 10

@interface ViewController ()<AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>



// other code here


 // !!!!!!! we're now sampling from the camera. My problem !!!!!!!!
self.currentState=STATE_SAMPLING;


// stop the app from sleeping
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

// update our UI on a timer every 0.1 seconds
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) stopCameraCapture {
[self.session stopRunning];
self.session=nil;
}

#pragma mark Pause and Resume of detection
-(void) pause {
if(self.currentState==STATE_PAUSED) return;

// switch off the torch
if([self.camera isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
    [self.camera lockForConfiguration:nil];
    self.camera.torchMode=AVCaptureTorchModeOff;
    [self.camera unlockForConfiguration];
}
self.currentState=STATE_PAUSED;
// let the application go to sleep if the phone is idle
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
}

-(void) resume {
if(self.currentState!=STATE_PAUSED) return;

// switch on the torch
if([self.camera isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
    [self.camera lockForConfiguration:nil];
    self.camera.torchMode=AVCaptureTorchModeOn;
    [self.camera unlockForConfiguration];
}
self.currentState=STATE_SAMPLING;
// stop the app from sleeping
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
}
```

Swift translation

```
// we're now sampling from the camera

enum CurrentState {
case statePaused
case stateSampling
}

var currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling

func setState(state: CurrentState){
            switch state
            {
            case .statePaused:
                // what goes here? Something like this?
            UIApplication sharedApplication.idleTimerDisabled = false
            case .stateSampling:
                // what goes here? Something like this?
            UIApplication sharedApplication.idleTimerDisabled = true
        }
        }

        // what goes here? Something like this?            
        currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide what your translated Swift enum looks like so I'm going to define one that seems to fit. Lets say your enum looks like this:

```
enum CurrentState 
{
    case statePaused
    case stateSampling
}
```

If you have a variable of type `CurrentState`, such as your `currentState` field,

you can give it a value like this:

```
currentState = CameraState.stateSampling
```

In Swift, enums are treated like real objects with type-safety, so if an object is declared as an enum type, you can use a shorter dot syntax like this if you'd like:

```
currentState = .stateSampling
```

There is much more information in the actual Swift documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html

**Update**

It seems like you are simply asking how to set the `idleTimerDisabled` property of the `UIApplication` `sharedApplication` singleton. You do that like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = false
```

Comment: Well, actually the question incorporates the setting of set the idleTimerDisabled property yes. But I did not know how to create the enum, function and cases for it. I'm new to programming so I guess I got lucky with the enum. Would I put your singleton in the case statements?  Like this? There are zero errors.  http://i.imgur.com/NtXU1WP.png

Comment: Your switch/case is now correct. But how are you calling `setState`? Keep in mind this will not be called when you set `currentState`, as it is not related to that property in any way (nor does it appear to set it). Are you trying to make it work with your `currentState` property?

Comment: ah yes. Do you see in the Objective-C at the bottom where it says `STATE_PAUSED` and `STATE_SAMPLING`? I will need to set those instances of currentState.   And the original goal was to deal with `self.currentState=STATE_SAMPLING;`

Comment: Hmmm I have to be careful here. Am I correctly understanding the original programmer's intention with the use of STATE_SAMPLING AND STATE_PAUSED? Using idleTimerDisabled in the 2 cases is what he was intending with his enum? And since the enum, var, function are created where is the best place to put them? Do all these blocks go inside or outside of viewDidLoad? Or should they go at the top of the beginSession() function?

Comment: The Objective-C code you posted doesn't make much sense because you cut too many things out. When you cut things out to only show relevant bits when asking a question, you should still include things like actual method declarations or in this case the method at all. You have a bunch of code sitting outside of any method and I can't understand where it should be.